# Sphere bundle of the tangent bundle of 2-dim sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let sph($\tau S^2$) be the sphere bundle of the tangent bundle of 2-dim$^l$ sphere. Could someone tell me why

sph($\tau S^2$)=$\mathbb{R}$P$^2$$\cup$$e^3$

holds? Where $e^3$ is a 3-dim$^l$ cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Proj}{\mathbf{P}}$Here's a sketch:

- The unit sphere bundle of $TS^{2}$ is homeomorphic to the rotation group $SO(3)$. (Idea of proof: An element of $SO(3)$ is essentially an ordered orthonormal basis of $\Reals^{3}$; projection to the first column is a map to $S^{2}$; the second column gives a unit vector in the tangent space at the first column. Because $SO(3)$ is a compact Hausdorff space, the preceding continuous bijection has continuous inverse.)
- The rotation group is homeomorphic to the three-dimensional real projective space $\Reals\Proj^{3}$. (Take a closed ball of radius $\pi$ in $\Reals^{3}$; map the center to the identity; map each non-zero point $x = |x|\cdot(x/|x|)$ to counterclockwise rotation by angle $x$ about the unit vector $x/|x|$. Show this map is continuous, bijective on the open ball, and identifies antipodal boundary points. As in the preceding bullet point, the map is consequently a homeomorphism between $SO(3)$ and the closed ball with antipodal boundary points identified.)
- The result of attaching a three-cell to the real projective plane $\Reals\Proj^{2}$ (via the antipodal map on the boundary sphere) is $\Reals\Proj^{3}$. (See preceding point.)